# MathJaX spacing in Safari (OS X)

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, safari

Since MathJaX got updated on MSE, I experience a lot of trouble with the spacing following formulae.See for example the spacing following $\dot C$ in the following picture.  [image: MathJaX spacing issue]

The period following $\min \dot{C}$ appears to be inside $\dot {C}$, while the period following the next $\dot {C}$ is placed as expected. So far I seem to be unable to deduce the reason for these inconsistencies or resolve this issue.

Technical Details: I use OS X 10.11.4, Safari 9.1 and the HTML-CSS rendering option for MathJaX. Using any other rendering option (common HTML, MathML, Preview HTML or SVG), I could not detect a similar issue - everything seems fine.

---

edit: Attempt to render the site locally:[image]

Comment: This looks like it could be https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1393 which should be fixed in the next release.

Comment: @Peter Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Could you try adding the CSS rule mentioned in the discussion locally to see if it helps?

Comment: @Peter Safari does not seem to be happy about rendering MathJax locally (see my edit above in a minute).

Comment: Oh. This is about the HTML-CSS output. Sorry, that must be a different problem than the one I linked to.

Comment: We'll have to look into it.

Comment: @Peter Sure, thanks. Let me know if I can be of any help.

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't reproduce the issue -- see screencast at https://saucelabs.com/beta/tests/96a9a901ae194325abb7ad927916c72e/watch. Not sure what to do. Maybe you just have some corrupted assets in your browser cache (either MathJax or SE) in which case clearing the cache might help you.

Comment: @Peter Clearing the cache actually resolved the issue. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Ah, that's great to hear. Thanks for following up.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/